# Failed to load the Frida native extension: DLL load failed

Tags: frida

OS: Windwos 10

Python: 3.6.0

Frida version: 12.2.15

```
frida-ps -U

***
Failed to load the Frida native extension: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Please ensure that the extension was compiled for Python 3.x.
***
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue. I saw about dependency to 3.6 python. I already have python 3.6. Any pointers to resolve this is really appreciated.

**Resolution**

Installed python 3.7 and installed python in a directory with out space.
Looks like frida acts weird if there is space in python path

Answer (score 0):

> Seems there is hardcoded a reference to python36.dll
>   somewhere in the ._frida.cp35-win32.pyd - saw this popping up on
>   procmon, and confirm via:
>
> PS C:\python353_x86\lib\site-packages> strings ._frida.cp35-win32.pyd
>   | sls python36.dll
>
> python36.dll
>
> Downloaded and installed python 3.6 and installed via pip there solved
>   it...

[Source](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/232)

`pip install frida --upgrade`

[Source 2](https://github.com/sensepost/objection/issues/94)

> Could you try with python 3.5? The 3.x binaries were built for 3.5

[Source 3](https://github.com/frida/frida-website/issues/51)

Comment: I'm already on python 3.6.0 and already tried upgrading frida. None of it worked